# How to correctly use Express 4 multiple routers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm attempting to use the Express 4 Router to use a different router based on the path. I want all `/api/v2/` routes handled by `version2`, and every other route handled by `version1`. The below setup serves me all the `version1` routes correctly, but seems to ignore `version2` as I get a 'Cannot GET...' message each time I test those endpoints.

routes.js:

```
var version1 = require('./routes/vers1');
var version2 = require('./routes/vers2');

module.exports = function(app) {

  app.all('/api/v2/*', version2);

  app.all('/*', version1);

};
```

Comment: I add my routes this way: `app.use('/', version1); app.use('/api/v2', version2);` i've never seen it done the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method routes (`.get`, `.post`, and of course `.all`) are terminal.  This is why you can use wildcards with them as well.  `.use` is not terminal and doesn't allow wildcards -- it acts as a prefix.  This is an implementation choice of express.  Use `.use` without wildcards.

- [`.use` does not set the layer route](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L458)
- [all other methods set the layer route](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L488)
- [if the route is set, layer attempts to handle the request](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L266).  Otherwise, the layer's path is stripped from the request route (`/api/v2` that you set in `.use` will be stripped).

The fact that `app.use("/*", version1)` works is purely incidental.  This will match any route and fall through to `version1[method](path)`.  Since there is no prefix to strip, if the request route matches `path`, express will consider this a match and serve that route.

Use `.use`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use .use not .all

.all is for middleware like authentication

http://expressjs.com/api.html